# Solr Scalability and Server requirement

Tags: solr

We are currently using Solr4.3 cloud in master slave mode and have been pretty happy with our initial solr POC. We are looking to store Social Data (tweets, blogs, Facebook feed) into Solr and make it searchable, also at the same time utilize the Faceting capabilities provided by Solr.

Going by the amount of social data that comes in, we were wondering what kind of infrastructure would be required to say store 2 TB or data and query them with minimum time.

Also, give the rate in which tweets come in what would be the best indexing strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to choose some cloud platform .**AWS** is one good option in this matter since you can always try and then change your machine if it does'nt suit your requirement.

So what will suit your requirement?

I think for solr since there is a high I/O I will suggest you to go with high I/O machine and good processing power
I suggest using

```
c3.2xlarge of AWS with  8 ecu,  15 gb ram,  2 x 80 SSD. 
and attach to it an EBS volume of atleast 4 TB.
```

This would solve your problem.